# What is the idiomatic way to collect data from multiple sources?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Imagine a data server with data randomly sharded between 40 nodes, from which you want to calculate a value on every 200 records. So load 200, calculate, load 200, calculate, etc. Your server is able to process 500 records per second, but you have enough bandwidth to read 50 records/second from each server (for a maximum throughput of 2000 records).

You could do this sequentially, which is the easiest option:

```
var cache = mutableListOf()
for (serv in servers) {
    for(record in serv.loadData()) {
        cache += record
        if (cache.count() == 500) {
            process(cache)
            cache.popFront(500)
        }

    }
}
```

This doesn't waste any space in memory, but only loads 50 records/s, and doesn't process the results in parallel. So another way is to get the results from all the servers first, and then iterate over that:

```
var queue = ConcurrentLinkedDeque()
coroutineScope {
    for (serv in servers) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            for (record in serv.loadData()) {
                queue += record
            }
        }
    }
}

for (batch in queue.chunked(500)) {
    process(batch)
}
```

This will make the most of your throughput, but wastes space in your concurrent queue, and as-is also doesn't allow processing and loading to occur in parallel.

So this seems like a good chance to utilize a `Flow`. We want to keep the ability to load from multiple sources in parallel, so we would replace `queue += record` with `emit(record)` and then batch & process the results in `collect{}` But `Flow.emit` isn't multi-thread safe (and the context changes due to the `launch`, but that can be overcome, even if it's undesirable).

Assuming `serv.loadData()` loads the data incrementally, this could still kinda be achieved by pausing data loading when the queue gets too full. But it feels really manual and clunky to write it that way.

So - assuming you don't care in what order the data is loaded - what is the idiomatic way of accomplishing this in the current version of Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `flatMapMerge`, which automatically parallelizes the inner flows you emit:

```
suspend fun main() {
    servers.asFlow()
            .flatMapMerge(servers.size) { server -> flow {
                for (record in server.loadData()) {
                    emit(record)
                }
            } }
            .chunked(500)
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // optional
            .collect { batch ->
                process(batch)
            }
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.chunked(size: Int) = flow {
    var chunk = mutableListOf<T>()
    collect {
        chunk.add(it)
        if (chunk.size == size) {
            emit(chunk)
            chunk = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    chunk.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.also { emit(it) }
}
```

Flow still doesn't have a standard implementation of `chunked` so I provided a quick-and-dirty one.

Comment: Nice; I guess I'm not the first one to run into this :)  Is my thinking off that this should take a dispatcher as well? It feels like from the outside, we know `loadData()` is an IO-bound operation, but it doesn't seem we have a way to specify to use `Dispatchers.IO`. Or is this concurrent collect done in some other way?

Comment: It depends on whether `loadData()` is a blocking or suspending function. I wrote this with the assumption of `suspend fun`. You can wrap the whole flow into `withContext(IO)`, or you can add `.flowOn(IO)` below `flatMapMerge`.